# Partial moment tag

Tags: discussion, tags

With this post [Partial quantile moments?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340468/partial-quantile-moments) there was introduced a new tag [partial-moments] (so far without tag wiki).  I think this (or some similar tag) could be useful, but my question is: What should its name be? What is this concept, as used in post such as [How does saddlepoint approximation work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781) or [When would we use tantiles and the medial, rather than quantiles and the median?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137931/when-would-we-use-tantiles-and-the-medial-rather-than-quantiles-and-the-median/142384#142384) (where I used the name "cumulative expectation").  I's sure this tag could be useful on other posts as well.

I'm not sure if this should be posted here or on the main site, since the questions: What should the tag name be? and what is the "official name" (and some references, please) ? belongs on each site respectively!

Comment: I think this Q belongs on meta.CV, where you asked it.

Comment: The very fact that you don't know what it's called suggests that the concept is so uncommon that we should not have a tag for it. I would suggest to remove the [partial-moments] tag.

Comment: google have multiple pages of hits, so maybe not that uncommon, but could still be known under other names ...